# Problems with jira permissions to step

Tags: jira

Please help me with `jira`, because I can't find needed docs in off site.
I have workflow (my personal, not default) and have step "close task". How  can I create the rule and where I can create there to see this button only admin user?

Thanks for the help.
(if not difficult, please write all steps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the edit workflow screen:

1. Click the transition "close task"
2. Under the options menu (on the right side of your screen), click "Conditions"
3. Click "Add Condition"
4. Select "User is in project role"
5. Be sure "Administrators" is selected, then click "Add"

I think this should solve your problem.

The Atlassian University training might be helpful for you:
https://university.atlassian.com/uac/2.0/courses/administrator/jira/v62/workflows/conditions-validators-post-functions#/lesson-content-header